# Selenium Error Without Any Print and Other Problems

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I writes a program to check whether a player has a cape or not in minecraft. I decided to use selenium and here are my problems:

1. Why does selenium show no error or display anything, but it does not work, because no open browser on windows and linux, so it cannot be windows fault as I thought.
2. How to do to program take the nicks from the list in another file (nick.py) and print how many player has a capes, in a row

Cape.py

> ```
> import requests,os
> from selenium import webdriver
> from time import sleep
> from nick import nickname
>
> class Checker:
>   def __init_(self, nickname):
>       self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>       self.driver.get("https://pl.namemc.com/")
>       sleep(2)
>
>       driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/div[2]/form/div/input")\
>           .send_keys(nickname)
>       driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/div[2]/form/div/div/button")\
>           .click()
>       name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/h1")
>       cape = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]")
>       print('name', " | ", 'cape')
>
> Checker()
> ```

Nick.py

```
 zandey
 and 
 other  
 nick
 minecraft
 players
```

Comment: Does the code work outside/without the class? _2._ is a different question entirely, and is likely too vague.

Answer (score 0):

In webdriver.Chrome() line, try adding the actual Chromedriver file path inbeetwen brackets.

Comment: Thx working, fix is copy webdriver exe to program folder and this is must by like:
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r'chromedriver.exe')